# PHP/JS: Multi-dim PHP array as Javascript Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a large php page with many complex variables on it and I am trying to create buttons that will play a video at certain points.

I currently have

```
<script>
    function generateJSON(){        
        var ARRAY = <?php echo json_encode($HCount) ?>;
        var vid = document.getElementById('my_video');
        vid.currentTime = parseInt(ARRAY[0].eventTime);
    }
</script>
<button id="goToTime" onClick="javascript:generateJSON()">genJS</button>
```

where echo json_encode($HCount) looks like

```
[{"gameID":"212345564","eventTime":"2693","plID":"523dfs",
"evArray":{"5645":"Cuyta","11245230":"98.0","2229":"","3318":"","15":""}},
{"gameID":"212345564","eventTime":"2293","plID":"523dft",
"evArray":{"5645":"Pkyyt","11245230":"28.0","2229":"","3318":"","11":""}}]
```

This code works however I would like the arguement of generateJSON to be the JSON itself.
i.e.

```
<script>
    function generateJSON(ARRAY){       
        var vid = document.getElementById('my_video');
        vid.currentTime = parseInt(ARRAY[0].eventTime);
    }
</script>
<button id="goToTime" onClick="javascript:generateJSON(<?php echo json_encode($HCount) ?>)">genJS</button>
```

^^ This code works for simple arrays such as

```
<?php
        $timeArray = array();
        $timeArray[] = 345.1;
        $timeArray[] = 789.1;
        $timeArray[] = 1002.1;
        $timeArray[] = 1200.12;
?>
```

but not for the multidimensional case I require, the error produced on Chrome is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

after the button but there are no ; in the line. I have tried adding ; to the php json_encode without much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `ARRAY[0]` restricts you to the first element in the array. Have you considered using something like `JSON.parse`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Please provide us with the sourcecode of the button, as it appears in HTML, and also remove "javascript:" from the onCLick handler. ANd can you post your generateJSON function?

Comment: I was only using ARRAY[0] as a test case. In the full code I have a global variable i that changes as you skip through the playlist. I have used json.parse and json.stringify when using simpler arrays, but not being able to parse from the button makes it challenging.

Comment: I have javascript in the handler because I am using a few different script languages. d3 etc. I assumed I needed to more cleanly define the script functions.

Comment: Just read the link could it be a having trailing commas in my json_encode()?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that now you are printing JSON to an element's attribute that is surrounded by quotes. You need to escape it in order to work, or the quotes in the JSON will break the element. Try this:

```
<button id="goToTime" onClick="generateJSON(<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($HCount)) ?>)">genJS</button>
```

Comment: <3. thanks a lot! This seems to have fixed my issues in my test case. I'll put it into my project to see what happens!